# Payment issue with PayPal REST API v1

Tags: php, paypal

I have used the PayPal REST API v1 for a client where it was deployed some time ago and it has been working fine up to a point.

Today it has come to my attention that the API integration has not been working since 16th Sept 2019.

The code has not changed since deployment but no submissions are going trough although the API is still receiving access tokens from PayPal successfully.

Below is the POST data I am sending to PayPal via CURL PHP (https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment)

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "application_context": {
        "brand_name": "[[REDACTED]]",
        "locale": "GB",
        "landing_page": "login",
        "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING",
        "user_action": "user_action=commit"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": "0.01",
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "payee": {
            "email": "[[REDACTED]]"
        },
        "description": "Test donation.",
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Test donation.",
                "description": "",
                "quantity": "1",
                "price": "0.01",
                "currency": "GBP"
            }]
        },
        "note_to_payee": "",
        "payment_options": {
            "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
        }
    }],
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "[[REDACTED]]",
        "cancel_url": "[[REDACTED]]"
    }
}
```

The response from PayPal is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "message": "Invalid request - see details",
    "debug_id": "[[REDACTED]]",
    "information_link": "https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/docs\/api\/payments\/#errors",
    "details": [{
        "field": "application_context.user_action",
        "location": "body",
        "issue": "{InvalidUserAction}"
    }]
}
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#definition-application_context), the value I have used for `application_context.user_action` is correct. I am aware the API is deprecated but there is no mention that the API is not functional.

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144143/paypal-express-checkout-with-option-useraction-commit-not-creating-transaction

Comment: I don't believe the above is related as they are not using the REST API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original documentation's specification is strangely repetitive

What happens if you now change it to `"user_action": "commit"` ?

Comment: Solved! Wow I didn't even think of this, I can't believe it used to work with the value `"user_action=commit"`